# Which type on pointer for byte parsing?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, type-conversion

I am working on a C++-Addon for nodejs which takes a nodejs Buffer object and does some binary operations on it. My current problem is about the data behind the pointer:

JavaScript environment:

```
var buf = new Buffer([0x00, 0x7e, 0xff, 0xff]);
```

C++ Backend code

```
int length = node::Buffer::Length(chunk);
char* head = node::Buffer::Data(chunk);

/* for debugging */
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    std::cout << hex << (int) head[i] << "\n";
}

/* outputs: 0x00 0x7e 0xffffffff 0xffffffff */
```

Why does the pointer interpret the two last bytes as 0xffffffff instead of 0xff?
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `char` is signed by default in your platform, so `(char)0xFF` is `-1`.

Just write:

```
std::cout << hex << (int)(unsigned char)head[i] << "\n";
```

It is useful sometimes to write:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

And then:

```
std::cout << hex << (int)(byte)head[i] << "\n";
```

Comment: There is already a nice type in `<cstdint>`: `uint8_t`. No need to add the `byte` type-alias.

Answer (score 3):

`char` is a signed type, which means that a `0xff` is -1, which is converted to -1 as `int`, which is represented as `0xffffffff`.

You can fix it like this:

```
std::cout << hex << (unsigned) (unsigned char) head[i] << "\n";
```

Comment: `char` may, or may _not_, be a signed type. It just happens to be signed on this particular system.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this type-cast: `(int) head[i]`. It is turning your result into a signed int. 0xff is -1 (as an signed char) which as a signed int is 0xfffffff.

Answer (score 1):

simply because the value is arithmetically extended from 1 byte to 4 bytes, 0xff means -1 (one byte) while still 0xffffffff means -1 (in 4 bytes), you have to use "unsigned char" for this purpose, as your "head" array.